# Keras takes long time to fit model

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am running a simple mnist python script from [here](https://keras.io/examples/vision/mnist_convnet/)

It seems the program stop at this line:

```
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, validation_split=0.1)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HP8w2.png)
It takes about >=30 mins ...

Some people say its about GPU memory [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/33364/why-model-fit-generator-in-keras-is-taking-so-much-time-even-before-picking-the).

I am using RTX 3080, cuda 11.2, cudnn 7.6, can someone help me?

Comment: Hi ! Did you check that your GPU was being used ? You can do this by using nvidia-smi

Comment: Yes, the power usage: 94w/320w, memory: 9GB/10GB, GPU-Util: 0%. Thank you for reply.

Comment: I was facing similar issue with CUDA 11. Downgrading it to CUDA 10 worked for me. You can give it a try

Answer (score 0):

`RTX 3080` cards are based on the `Ampere` architecture for which compatible `CUDA` version start with `11.x`, `cuDNN` version starts with `8.x` and Tensorflow version `2.4`.

You can try to upgrade cuDNN version accordingly, your issue will be resolved. For more details you can refer [CuDNN support matrix](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/cudnn/support-matrix/index.html).